# Can I play CoD: Advanced Warfare with only one content package?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I got Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare this morning (Merry Christmas) and I tried to play it. Turns out my Xbox 360 only has 4GB and I was only able to install one of the two content packages (there's only two, right?). I'm getting a hard drive sometime on the next week or so, but I was wondering if I would be able to play with only content package one installed. I'm mostly interested in playing the campaign, but I have Xbox Live Gold so playing multiplayer would be fine too.

Comment: Have you actually tried playing it at all yet?

Comment: @FinnRayment No I dont want to mess up the game

Comment: Well first of all, it's on a CD/DVD. Your not going to mess it up. Second of all, if it does miraculously stuff up, uninstall it and reinstall it. Lastly, I'm pretty sure Microsoft would be smart enough to put warnings in like "This game is unplayable. Please install the second package blah blah blah" Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing the game with only one package installed I found that you can only play Local Play. You get an error message for campaign and for Xbox Live it just doesn't connect.

Answer (score 0):

I started playing xbox live when I first got it and I didn't install the campaign and it worked fine